# Expected diameter of a random point set

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, probability-distributions, measure-concentration

**General problem:** For a point set $S\subset X$ in a metric space $(X,d)$, let $\text{diam}(S)=\max_{x,y\in S}d(x,y)$. Given a distribution $P$ on $X$ and $m$ i.i.d. points $x_1,\ldots,x_m\sim P$, what is $\mathbb{E} \text{diam}(S)$?

**Special case:** $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, $d$ is Euclidean distance, and $P=N(0,\Sigma)$.

In particular, I am interested in the case where $P$ has unbounded support, which rules out the reference [1] below. Of course, in the general case we would assume some kind of concentration for $P$, etc.

A more reasonable request is upper and lower bounds on $\mathbb{E} \text{diam}(S)$, or high-probability bounds on $\text{diam}(S)$. This seems like too simple of a problem to not have been studied, but I have not found anything besides this paper:

[1] Limit Laws for the Diameter of a Random Point Set,
Martin J. B. Appel, Christopher A. Najim and Ralph P. Russo,
Advances in Applied Probability,
Vol. 34, No. 1 (Mar., 2002), pp. 1-10.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1428368

Comment: Just a comment. In your special case, you lose nothing by assuming $\Sigma$ is diagonal (and appear to gain quite a bit).

Comment: $\lambda R$ and $\Lambda R$ provide reasonable bounds for the special case, where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$, $\Lambda$ is the sum of the eigenvalues, and $R$ is the expected range for $m$ standard normal variables. $R$ is roughly twice the $m/(m+1)$ quantile, and is discussed in the literature. It’s also straightforward to write down expressions for the probabilities that these bounds are exceeded; it’s just the asymptotics of those expressions that are messy.

Comment: @MattF. What is "expected range"?

Comment: The expected range is the expectation of the max minus the min.

Comment: @MattF. Thanks. Can you point me to this literature? It seems clear that crude bounds can be found by bounding expected suprema or order statistics (as you suggest), but I'd be curious to see if anyone has tried anything more sophisticated.

Comment: @user34500, I’ll leave googling that to you, or you can check the references in the first paragraph of the paper mentioned in the question. I am now downvoting the question for a lack of research before posting.